# What does "IPv4 addresses in the same AS" mean?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, ipv4

I'm in the process of moving a website from HostGator to Amazon EC2. Front end and back end are both moved. I added a Hosted Zone in Amazon Route 53 and updated my nameservers in HostGator. Unfortunately, the site won't load.

I ran a check with Zonemaster and received the following warnings:

> All nameservers in the delegation have IPv4 addresses in the same AS
>   (16509). All nameservers in the delegation have IPv6 addresses in the
>   same AS (16509).   All nameservers in the delegation are in the same AS
>   (16509).

I've searched but can't figure out what "AS" means in this context. Would love some help to point me in the right direction for troubleshooting.

The domain in question is tektonbody.com.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AS refers to [Autonomous System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) which in rough terms means "block of IPs that share common routing" or in more general terms "are from the same allocation block".

You're getting this warning because the nameservers are all in the same block and if that single route goes offline for some reason, all your nameservers go down. It's generally best to spread these out geographically to minimize your exposure to localized events.

They're just looking out for you here. Typically you should have 3-4 different nameservers on different backbone providers in different regions so that no single failure, even at the provider level, can take them all down.

Comment: Ah, so it's a warning, not what's actually preventing my domain name from resolving, correct?

Comment: It's an advisory you should observe, but technically it should work. They're just saying your DNS is hanging by a thread.

Comment: The common origin AS seems pretty much meaningless in this case... the Route 53 DNS server address blocks are anycast, so coming from the same AS should reveal little or nothing about actual routing or resilience.  Each hosted zone has 4 assigned name server addresses, which appear to be from 4 separate advertisements, all coming from AS 16509 on IPv4... and the same again for IPv6.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That's a good point. UDP services can be multi-homed that way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an A record pointing to the IP of our ec2 instance fixed this issue for me

We are migrating from OVH to AWS

Comment: I'm also trying the same OVH to AWS, I have update the DNS Nameserver to AWS Route 53 Nameservers in OVH DNS Manager. Is it enough or do I need to have anyother configuration in OVH? Already I have defined the DNS records in AWS Route 53.